# Does Visual Studio's application crash dump also contain source code in it?

Tags: c++, crash, dump

I'm developing a Windows application in Visual Studio. The application is used to host third party plugin. One of those plugins is crashing my application. The plugin developer asked for application crash dump from my application to better see where in their own plugin the crash is happening.

For this I need to know if Visual Studio's application crash dump contains also the source code of my own application, which I don't want to send to the developer, as it's proprietary IP.

So does the Visual Studio crash dump contain also the source code? If it does, is there a way around this so I can send something useful for the third party plugin developer so they can fix their bug?

EDIT:
I think I'll go with the minimal reproducible example suggested by user7860670. Sounds like a good advice.

Comment: What is proprietary IP? Crash dumps are program memory dumps. How do you think, do they have sources?

Comment: _"...crash dump contains also the source code..."_ no.  You might want to provide the 3rd party with the PDB that matches the dump to make their life a bit easier.

Comment: You might get better answer by asking on Microsoft support channels directly.

Comment: A better idea would be to create a [mcve] and send it to plugin developers so they can reproduce the problem. 1) This will ensure that problem is not within you application. 2) This will make their life easier and lead to faster issue solving (no more "it works on my PC" shit). 3) Neither code of your application or debug symbols are shared.

Comment: I think I'll go with the minimal reproducible example suggested by user7860670. Sounds like a good advice.